# Require password every time drive/partition is accessed?

Tags: macos, partition, security, ssd, password

I just created a new partition on my macbook's SSD set to Journaled/Encrypted.

It seems I only get prompted for the password once, when the macbook is turned on, rather than every time I try to access it.

How can I make this drive inaccessible unless a password is provided on-the-spot?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible with encrypted partitions, so If you will not find a solution - consider using encrypted disk images instead. They will ask password every time you mount them.

Comment: @toma but mounting only happens once right? If not, how do I do this?

Comment: the scenario of usage is 1. login to your account 2. mount encrypted image 3. work with secure data 4. unmount. Also you can try to automate mount/unmount using Apple Script or sh. http://osxdaily.com/2013/05/13/mount-unmount-drives-from-the-command-line-in-mac-os-x/

Comment: @toma but I want to be password prompted every time I try to read/write

Comment: Well, that is the problem. I don't think it is possible to require password on read/write - it can be done only on mount. As I know, HFS driver is not designed to work as you expect in this case. You can try to search some 3-rd party solutions, that will provide virtual drive (WebDav), that will redirect read/write calls to encrypted drive, and mount/unmount it when needed.